# JPA in spring-boot project "batch insert" very slow

Tags: java, jpa, spring-boot, batch-insert

Hey I'm trying to insert some 800 rows with `@oneToMany` relationships, but it seems they are really slow. Which I don't quite understand why, since I've read some guides that said it should be fairly quick.
So I hope that some kind soul could tell me if there is something I've misunderstood and can help me increase the performance of the insertions.

**The Repository:**

```
@Repository
public interface FootnoteRepository extends CrudRepository<FootnotesEntity, Long> {

    @Query("FROM FOOTNOTES WHERE number =?1 AND FOOTNOTE_TYPE=?2 order by DATE_START desc,id asc")
    public List<FootnotesEntity> findFootnoteByNumberAndType(Long number, String transportNumber, Pageable pageable);
}
```

**The DomainClass:**

```
@Autowired
private EntityRepository entityRepository;

@Autowired
private FootnoteRepository footnoteRepository;
/**
 * Handles the JPA Interface
 * 
 * @param
 * @return the success of the operation
 */
@Transactional
private boolean insertUpdateFootnoteEntities(List<FootnotesEntity> footnotes) {
    boolean success = true;
    System.out.println("footnotes: " + footnotes.size());
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    try {
        // TODO fix below: (does not "commit" the deletion")
        // footnoteRepository.deleteAll();

        // TODO speed optimize
        footnoteRepository.save(footnotes);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        success = false;
    }
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("time: " + (end - start));
    return success;
}
```

For this class I've also tried adding batchsize, and using the nonspecific repository(basicly an EntityManager)'s method: `.persist(entity)`

**'Parent' Entity Class:**

```
@Table(indexes = { @Index(columnList = "FOOTNOTE_NUMBER,FOOTNOTE_TYPE") }, uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {
        "FOOTNOTE_NUMBER", "FOOTNOTE_TYPE", "DATE_START" }))
@Entity(name = "FOOTNOTES")
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class FootnotesEntity extends BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "FOOTNOTES_ID")
    protected Long id;

    @Column(name = "FOOTNOTE_NUMBER")
    protected Long number;

    @Column(name = "FOOTNOTE_TYPE")
    protected String footnoteType;

    @Column(name = "APPLICATION_CODE")
    private String applicationCode;

    @Column(name = "shortDescription", length = 2000)
    private String shortDescription;

    @Column(name = "DATE_START")
    private Date startDate;

    @Column(name = "DATE_END")
    private Date endDate;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "footnote", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @OrderBy("startDate desc")
    protected List<DescriptionPeriodsEntity> descriptionPeriods;
}
```

**'Child' Entity Class:**

```
@Entity(name = "DESCRIPTION_PERIODS")
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class DescriptionPeriodsEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION_PERIODS_ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "DATE_START")
    private Date startDate;

    @Column(name = "DATE_END")
    private Date endDate;

    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION", length = 5000)
    protected String description;

    @Column(name = "LANGUAGES_ID")
    protected String languagesId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name = "FOOTNOTES_ID")
    protected FootnotesEntity footnote;

}
```

**Current runtime:**
Above 4 minutes(276642ms) to do the inserts (796 footnote rows and 900 descriptionPeriodes)

Comment: A private method isn't usually `@Transactional` (unless you do some serious wrangling with AspectJ). Maybe your assumption about how fast it should be is predicated on a false premise about the number of network round trips involved?. Your comment about the commit suggests as much, but I'm not sure I know enough about the assumptions.

Comment: All i want is to save these two objects, which refers to eachother as fast as possible.

Comment: I tried to remove the @Transactional, now it's down to 1/4 of the time. Could you make an answer explaining why?

Comment: The problem with your code is that it runs in a single transactions. Which means the first level cache is filling up. When a save is done all the objects in the first level cache are checked if they are dirty. Now this isn't a problem with 10 objects but adds up with each addition. In your loop what you should do is add a `flush` and `clear` after you reached your defined batch size. That will clear the cache and you will keep your performance. While still maintaining a single tx. The problem with multiple tx's is that when one fails the others remain committed.

Comment: I actually did try it with a batchsize 20, and flush and clear. It did not seem to make a difference..
But when you have It like I do above, with classes that have a relationship. How should you calcualte the @batchsize, if i set it to 20 on each of the tables/entities, when is it then time for me to clear and flush? 20 total? or when either one of them reaches 20 first?